# SQLiteException without code

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:932)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:543)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
  at com.grydmitrij.ticketpdddemo.bd.DBTheme.getThemeNames (DBTheme.java:52)
  at com.grydmitrij.ticketpdddemo.adapters.SelectTicketAdapterForThemes.<init> (SelectTicketAdapterForThemes.java:46)
  at com.grydmitrij.ticketpdddemo.SelectTicketForThemes.getAdapter (SelectTicketForThemes.java:21)
  at com.grydmitrij.ticketpdddemo.abstracts.SelectTicketFor.onCreateView (SelectTicketFor.java:31)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2080)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1108)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:801)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManager.java:1638)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:679)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1240)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1088)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1614)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1085)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:758)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:640)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1464)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:758)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:640)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6120)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:702)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:19734)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2729)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1816)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2065)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1704)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6857)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:871)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:683)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:619)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:857)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6102)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The SQLiteException is thrown only for ZTE Blade phone. This code works for other phones.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgOW7.png)
The Ticket2 table exists. I haven't this phone and I can't check the problem.

**SelectTicketAdapterForThemes.java**

```
44 DBTheme dbTheme = new DBTheme(activity);
45 dbTheme.openBase();
46 themeNames = dbTheme.getThemeNames();
```

**DBTheme.java**

```
14  public DBTheme(Context context)
15  {
16      PDDHelper=new DataBasePDDHelper(context);
17  }
18  
19  public void openBase()
20  {
21      if (sqPDD==null)
22          sqPDD=PDDHelper.getReadableDatabase();
23  }
...
47  public String [] getThemeNames()
48  {
49      if (sqPDD==null)
50          openBase();
51      String sql="SELECT * FROM Ticket2";
52      Cursor cursor=sqPDD.rawQuery(sql, null);
...
```

**DataBasePDDHelper.java**

```
   24   public DataBasePDDHelper(Context context)
   25   {       
   26       super(context, NAME_PDD, null, VER_PDD);
   27       this.context=context;
   28       if (context == null)
   29           return;
   30       PATH_PDD = context.getDatabasePath(NAME_PDD).getPath();
   31       
   32
   33       createDataBase();
   34   }
    ...
   79   private void createDataBase() //throws IOException
   80   {
   81       
   82       boolean dbExist=checkDataBase(PATH_PDD);
   83       //dbExist=false;
   84       if (!dbExist) //если база данных еще не создана, то создать
   85       {
   86           this.getWritableDatabase();     //создаем сначала пустую БД
   87           try
   88           {
   89               copyDataBase(PATH_PDD);
   90           }
   91           catch(Exception e)
   92           {
   ...                 
   101          }
   102      }
   103   }
```

PS. Update. I added full stack trace. But stack was not complete at the end. It is complete at the beginning. Google Play Console show it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jREUL.png)

PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: This is not the complete stack trace; the actual error message at the beginning is missing.

Comment: It is complete stack trace at the beginning. I add stack at the end and photo with the exception.

Comment: It is usually error message is more complete. For example, `SQLiteException: no such table (code...)`. But this stack trace haven't additional message.

Comment: did you find a solution? experiencing the same problem and only with zte phones and just few crashes on lenovo

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution?